# How to solve Webpack fonts and svg image loader Regex conflict?

Tags: webpack

Here is my regex for fonts and svg image loader and they are in conflict, since they both target *.svg file. How to solve it?

```
 {test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file?name=/Presentation/_dist/fonts/Interstate/[name].[ext]'},
 {test:/\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&name=/Presentation/_dist/images/[name].[ext]'}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`exclude`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders) and [`include`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders) to eliminate the problem.
Something like:

```
{
    test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
    include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "MY-FONTS-FOLDER")
        //, Any other svg font path
    ],
    loader: 'file?name=/Presentation/_dist/fonts/Interstate/[name].[ext]'
},
{
    test:/\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    exclude: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "MY-FONTS-FOLDER")
        //, Any other svg font path
    ],
    loader: 'url?limit=10000&name=/Presentation/_dist/images/[name].[ext]'
}
```

Note:

- Replace `MY-FONTS-FOLDER` with the actual fonts folder path.
- You might also use regex to match `font.svg` for the file-loader and `.svg` BUT NOT `font.svg`(maybe negative lookahead) for url-loader.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought about that!